# Get value of first <td> element in same row as input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text from the first td tag from each row by using the input button as shown below:

```
for(var i in obj.questions){
    question += '<tr class="row">';
    question += "<td>"+ obj.questions[i].question+"</td>";
    question += '<td><input type="button" class="question" value="Add question" onclick="addQuestion()"></td>';
    question += "</tr>";
    document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML = question;        
}
```

The `id=t01` is for the table tag. Here is the js that I tried working on but is not working:

```
var question;
$('.question').click(function() {
    question = $(this).parent().find('td:first-child').text();                    
 });
```

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `.live()` to achieve this, depending on the order of your event binding and HTML generation. Also, consider revising your `click` event logic so that you iterate over all rows of the table to access the text of "first cell" for each table row:

```
// When the .question input is added to the DOM, this event logic will
// be bound to the input element automatically
$(document).live('.question', 'click', function() {

    var question;

    // Iterate over each row of the table
    $('#t01 .row').forEach(function() {

      // For each row, extract the text from first row cell
      var row = $(this);
      var firstCell = row.find('td:first-child');
      var firstCellText = firstCell.text();

      // Not sure how you want to use the data, this shows 
      // how to construct a comma separated string of text 
      // from all first row cells
      question += firstCellText + ',';
    });

    // Print result to console
    console.log(question);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through each row like below

```
$('.question').click(function () {

  $('#t01 .row').each(function () {

    console.log($(this).find("td:first-child").text());
  });
});
```

Also I would suggest to write html use jQuery instead of javascript instead of  **document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML**

```
$('#t01').html(question);
```

Also your implementation of creating rows dynamically have one problem , you will get only one row every time. You can change your code like below

```
var question = "";
for (var i in questions) {
  question += '<tr class="row">';
  question += "<td>" + questions[i].question + "</td>";
  question += '<td><input type="button" class="question" value="Add question" onclick="addQuestion()"></td>';
  question += "</tr>";

}
$('#t01').html(question);
```

I have created a running sample for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-n4spxc?file=index.js